# Stack Attribute not found in Pyhton

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I am running a finger vein recognition pyhon code. When I wish to convert my dataframe to stack, there always a error **"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'. Did you mean: 'unstack'?"**. I have tried through Python ver 8, 11, and 12, but still cannot solve the problem.
`df = pd.Series(sorted(glob(user_location))) df = df.apply(get_image_path2, args=(sample_location,)).stack(future_stack=True) df = df.rename_axis(index=['users', 'samples'])`

the user_location is 20151211-utwente-vingervein/dataset/data/*
the sample location is something like this ????_1_*.png

Is that possible the version that I downloaded not included stack attribute?

Comment: your `df` is a Series, and Series don't have a `stack` method.

Comment: Provide a [mre], what is `sorted(glob(user_location))`? What is `df` after running `df.apply(get_image_path2, args=(sample_location,))`?

Comment: chk `print(df.apply(get_image_path2, args=(sample_location)).head())`

Comment: @PandaKim or, better, `df.apply(get_image_path2, args=(sample_location)).head().to_dict('tight')`

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Series has no attribute stack(), therefore, use the unstack() comes out expected result.